# Laravel: How to receive multidimensional resultsets using eloquent orm

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i have two tables: Users and Followers.

#### user

id, username
1, foo
2, bar
3, test

#### followers

id, user_id_follows, user_id_followed
1, 2, 1
2, 3, 1

Which means that the users "bar" and "test" follow the user "foo".

I would like to have a result-set like:
[
 id: "foo",
 username: "bar",
 followers: ["bar", "test"]
]

Alternatively as JSON object.
Is this possible with eloquent ORM? user has a hasMany-relationship to follower and follower belongsTo user.
Is it possible to get the relations but only the usernames of the followers?
I also tried to do this via raw-sql query. But using DB::select(DB::raw($query)); gets me an non-multidimensional object which means that "followers" only has "bar" and not both followers.

So what is the best way to get a multidimensional result-set?
Can i still rely on eloquentORM? How?

Thank you and best regards
Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a much better way.  What we will do is create a many to many relationship with the users table to the users table and use your followers table as the pivot table.  I've also done some extra work so you can view both followeds and followers for a user.

Unfortunately, the way you have your tables setup didn't make a lot of sense to me, so my followers table looks like `id`, `user_id`, `follow_id`.  This way, I can easily find who a user is following by looking up that user's id in the `user_id` column and I can see who that user is followed by, by looking up his user_id in the `follow_id` column.  Maybe this is what you meant with your table, in which case, you could just drop in the column names you have.  With that in mind, here is what I did.

In your User model.

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','followers','user_id_followed','user_id_follows');
}

public function followeds()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User','followers','user_id_follows','user_id_followed');
}
```

In my controller, to get the json....

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->load('followers');
$user->load('followeds');
$json = $user->toJson();
echo $json;
```

Obviously if you just wanted the followers, just `$user->load('followers');`

Comment: I need to prepend "->get()" before the toJson. However, it does not work. I know have the "user"-column in the result-set. But i don't get the username. But it is in the right way. I tried a bit but couldn't figure out a solution. Perhaps it is also neccessary to append a where-clause to the select-clause? What do you think.

Comment: I've modified my answer to something I just built and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: And I just figured out the way you have your ID's which is backwards from mine.  So my `user_id` would correspond with your `user_id_followed` and my `follow_id` would correspond with your `user_id_follows`.  I'll update the answer to work with your table.

Comment: Thank you very well! Yes the naming of my columns may be confusing.. it is user_id_follows for the one who follows and user_id_followed (user_id) for the one who is followed (follow_id). I have a small follow-up-question: Is it possible to reduce the resultset (just of the followers) to the username? Otherwise i get the full user-object for each follower.

Comment: I've tried and I can't seem to get it working with `select()`.  It feels like there should be a way to do it with Eloquent.  The only solution I can come up with is loop through the users object and set `$user->followers` to just `$user->followers->username;`